# Verificar qual campo já é existente na tabela

Tags: php, laravel

Estou fazendo uma consulta no Laravel para ver se o usuário com o e-mail, CPF ou username digitados já existe na base de dados.

```
# Verificar se Usuário Já Existe na Base de Dados
$verUser       = User::whereEmail($email)
                        ->orWhereCpf($cpf)
                        ->orWhereUsername($username)
                        ->first();
if($verUser){
    Session::flash('alert-error', 'Um usuário já existe na base de dados.');
    return redirect()->to('auth/login');
}
```

É mais por curiosidade. Tem como saber qual dos campos entrou na condição do SELECT ?

Se é o e-mail, CPF ou username que já é existente ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A forma mais fácil de fazer isso é utilizando a regra `unique` do Validator antes de registrar seu usuário.

Caso esteja utilizando Laravel 5+, verifique as regras de validation no seu `AuthController`, deixe ele parecido com isso:

```
/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'username' => 'required|unique:users',
        'cpf' => 'required|unique:users',   
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}
```

Assim quando houver algum problema com esses campos o Laravel irá retornar uma mensagem de erro específica para cada campo no momento do cadastro.

Outra forma de fazer isso é verificando o retorno de cada campo:

```
$verUser = User::whereEmail($email)
              ->orWhereCpf($cpf)
              ->orWhereUsername($username)
              ->first();

if($verUser){

    $camposRepetidos = [];

    if ($verUser->username === $username) {
        $camposRepetidos[] = 'Username';
    }

    if ($verUser->cpf === $cpf) {
        $camposRepetidos[] = 'CPF';
    }

    if ($verUser->email === $email) {
        $camposRepetidos[] = 'E-mail';
    }

    $mensagem = 'Um usuário já existe na base de dados. 
                 Verifique os seguintes campos: ' . implode(',', $camposRepetidos);

    Session::flash('alert-error', $mensagem);
    return redirect()->to('auth/login');
}
```